# Representation of the analytical solution to the Poisson equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, finite-element-method, poissons-equation

I have the following 1-dimensional Poisson's problem with the corresponding boundary conditions:

$$
u_{xx} = -f(x) ; \quad u(1) = g, \quad -u_x(0) = h
$$
on a open domain
$$
\Omega = (0,1)
$$

Is it correct to represent an analytical solution as follows?

First, integrating with respect to $x$ once from $0$ to $y$:

$$
\int_0^y u_{xx} dx = -\int_0^y f(x)dx 
$$

to obtain:
$$
u_x(y) - u_x(0) = -\int_0^y f(x)dx
$$
Applying the BC,
$$
u_x(y) = -\int_0^y f(x)dx + h 
$$
Let $$ f(z) = \int_0^y f(x)dx $$

and then integrating the previous equation with respect to $y$ from $x$ to $1$:
$$
u(1) - u(x) = \int_x^1 f(z)dy + hy|_x^1 
$$
Applying the boundary condition $u(1)=g$ and then putting $f(z)$ back to its original form:
$$
u(x) = g + h(1-x) + \int_x^1 \left[ \int_0^y f(x)dx \right]dy
$$
I'm doing this since I require the representation of the exact solution to compare with the solution obtained from the Galerkin approximation. **Is there anything wrong with the steps I've shown above?** Please criticize.

Comment: You should not overload the symbol $f$ like that. Drag in a new symbol for the antiderivative instead, or just carry it around as is.

Comment: @Ian Do you mean something like? $ p(z)=\int_0^y f(x) dx $

Comment: Except the variables should match up on LHS and RHS, so either $p(y)$ or integrate up to $z$.

Comment: @Ian oh ok now I understand. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check it.

$$u(x)=g+h\cdot (1-x)+\int_{x}^1\int_0^y f(t)\mathrm dt \mathrm dy \\ u'(x)=-h+\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\int_{x}^1\int_0^y f(t)\mathrm dt \mathrm dy\right) \\ =-h-\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm dt$$
$$u''(x)=-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm dt=-f(x)$$

And,
$$u(1)=g+\underbrace{h\cdot(1-1)}_{=0}+\underbrace{\int_1^1\cdots}_{=0}=g$$
$$u'(0)=-h-\underbrace{\int_{0}^0\cdots}_{=0}$$

Everything looks good.

---

**In regards to the second line.**

Let $F(y)=\int_0^y f(t)\mathrm dt$. Then,
$$u'(x)=-h+\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_x^1 F(y)\mathrm dy \\ =-h-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_1^x F(y)\mathrm dy$$
By the [FTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), this is
$$u'(x)=-h-F(x) \\ =-h-\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm dt$$
The rest follows.

Comment: Hi, could you explain how the derivative with respect to x of the integral on the RHS in the 2nd line obtains the expression in line 3. My calculus is shaky which is why I’m asking. Thanks

Comment: @howstheJosh Done.